# $$eval is returning undefined. In pupeteer js

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I'm currently trying to get the img src of an html file and I'm having a problem.  I'm not exactly sure how to go about it.  Let me explain:

I have several of these divs in an html page:

```
<div class="photo-tile photo-tile-small"><img class="photo-tile-image" src="https://photos.example.com/images/randomimage.jpg"></div>
```

I am attempting to get the src of the page all of them.  In example here it would be: https://photos.example.com/images/randomimage.jpg"
If there's 10 on the page I want all 10.

Using puppeteer js this is my code to try and attempt this:
(Not all of it just the relevant part):

```
  const getImgSrc = await page.$$eval('.photo-tile-image', img => img);
  console.log(getImgSrc);
```

This returns "undefined".  My understanding of this (I'm sure that I'm wrong), is that here
$$.eval is evaluating every instance of this element called '.photo-tile-image', it would return the properties of the element in this case it would be called `img` from here I would expect it to log out the result in `console.log(getImgSrc)`

getting passed this point how then would I get `img.src`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The argument of the function you are passing to `$$eval` is not an image but the array of images.

So from there, you can do:

```js
const getImgSrc = await page.$$eval('.photo-tile-image', imgs => imgs.map(img => img.src));
console.log(getImgSrc);
```